# Returning top 3 count values in sql queries

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have grouped my table based on a column field, and simultaneously displayed count value for each group.
For example

```
user   |    count(user)
user 1 |     4
user 2 |     3
user 3 |     3
user 4 |     3
user 5 |     2
```

Now I need to display only top 3 users count in this case user 1, user2, user 3, user 4.

I have written the grouping logic but when I try to order values of count by desc and then restrict the result to 3(Limit 3), I only get user 1,2, and 3. Which is not correct because user 4 also comes in top 3 count.

Comment: please test it: SELECT `user`, COUNT(`user`) FROM`table` GROUP BY `user` HAVING MAX COUNT(`user`)

Comment: Is this [tag:mysql] or [tag:sqlite]?

Answer (score 1):

By first determining the cutoff value with a separate select it will be easier (for MySql):

```
SELECT MIN(cnt) 
INTO @min 
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) cnt 
  FROM Table 
  GROUP BY user
  ORDER BY cnt DESC
  LIMIT 3
) t;

SELECT user, COUNT(*) usercount
FROM Table
GROUP BY user
HAVING usercount>= @min
ORDER BY usercount DESC;
```

Also see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d749/2

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

select user, count(1) from users group by user having count(user) >= (select count(1) from users group by user order by count(user) desc limit 2, 1) order by count(user)

```
Example table:
mysql> select * from users;
+----+-------+
| id | user  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | user1 |
|  3 | user3 |
|  4 | user4 |
|  5 | user5 |
|  6 | user1 |
|  7 | user2 |
|  8 | user2 |
|  9 | user2 |
| 10 | user2 |
| 11 | user1 |
| 12 | user5 |
| 13 | user5 |
| 14 | user6 |
| 15 | user6 |
| 16 | user6 |
+----+-------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select user, count(1) from users group by user having count(user) >= (select count(1) from users group by user order by count(user) desc limit 2, 1) order by count(user) desc;
+-------+----------+
| user  | count(1) |
+-------+----------+
| user2 |        4 |
| user1 |        3 |
| user5 |        3 |
| user6 |        3 |
+-------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So trick is to figure out what the 3rd highest count value is.  Then get all users who have a count >= to that (so it includes users who are tied for 3rd place).

The subquery with LIMIT 2, 1 is used to get the 3rd highest count value.  So you could use LIMIT 4, 1 if you wanted the 5 highest instead of 3.